# Windows 10 find an opened window by name and focus on it

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there a built-in feature in Windows that allows you to find and focus on a window by typing in its name?

I have a work-related issue when I need to run like 60+ different servers and it looks like this:
[image]

It is hard to find the correct one in this mess.

They all have different names, though. I thought it might be possible to focus on it from Task Manager, but it can't bring up a window with a running process to the front of other windows for some reason.

Task View can only show them but doesn't allow to search window by name and scrolling through all of them is prone to missing the right one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a built-in feature, but there *is* a Microsoft-owned tool that you can install.

Microsoft's [PowerToys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/run), a suite of Windows utilities, includes a tool known as "PowerToys Run", which is an extension of an older project known as [WindowWalker](https://github.com/betsegaw/windowwalker/).

Once PowerToys Run is installed and enabled you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (default shortcut) and search for a window by name. Specifying the prefix `<` ensures that the search is filtered to only include running processes and not other things that PowerToys Run is aware of. Here's an [animation](https://github.com/betsegaw/windowwalker/raw/master/Window-Walker.gif).

Comment: thanks, it is a useful tool for this task!